# opening links with apex:detail using apex:composition

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-template

I have a visualforce page using an apex:composition with a template specified.

within this page, I am displaying an apex:detail of an object's detail page. However, the links on the detail page specifically **Edit Button** opens in standard salesforce styling instead of my template styling. Is there a way I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

Only by overriding the standard edit page with your own Visualforce page.  The apex:detail component puts out buttons with standard functionality, and you can't influence those in a supported fashion.  You could write some JavaScript that locates the buttons and changes the targets from the standard page to your Visualforce page, but that would be fragile as if Salesforce changed the way the buttons worked, your JavaScript might not be able to locate and update them, thus suddenly re-introducing the default behaviour.